# An interesting inequality related to graphs

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

> Let $x_1,\cdots x_{k+1}$ be real numbers, where $k\geq 1$. Prove that $k.\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}(x_1-x_i)^2 \geq \sum_{2\leq i,j\leq k+1, i<j}(x_i-x_j)^2$.

I am trying to apply [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). The inequality can be explained as follows : Let $S$ be star graph on vertices $\{1,2,\cdots,k+1\}$ with $1$ as the center. Let $K$ be the complete graph on vertices $\{2,3,\cdots,k+1\}$. The above inequality would then imply that $k.L_{S} - L_{K}$ is positive semi-definite. Here $L_G$ is the Laplacian associated with the graph $G$. This lemma is from this [paper](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/Pubs/support-graph.pdf). [Lemma 2.10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$k^2x_1^2-2k\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}x_i+k\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}-(k-1)\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}+2\sum_{2\leq i<j\leq k+1}x_ix_j\geq0,$$

which is just $$\left(kx_1-\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}x_i\right)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Nice. In the last term, it should be $k+1$ instead of $k+2$.

Comment: @Sudipta Roy It was typo. I fixed. Thank you!